# Error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '{' token

Tags: c

I've been trying to learn C from a book called [C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789751984) and I have come across a problem and the one bad thing is you can't ask a book a question! Typed the error into Google and it brought me to this site. The error I'm getting is in the question title and this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main(

{

 //Set up the variables, as well as define a few

    char firstInitial, middleInitial;
    int number_of_pencils;
    int number_of_notebooks;
    float pencils = 0.23;
    float notebooks = 2.89;
    float lunchbox = 4.99;


    //The information for the first child
    firstInitial = 'J';
    middleInitial = 'R';

    number_of_pencils = 7;
    number_of_notebooks = 4;

    printf("%c%c needs %d pencils, %d notebooks, and 1 lunchbox\n",
        firstInitial, middleInitial,number_of_pencils,
        number_of_notebooks);
    printf("The total cost is £%.2f\n\n", number_of_pencils*pencils + number_of_notebooks*notebooks + lunchbox);

    //The information for the second child
    firstInitial ='A';
    middleInitial = 'J';

    number_of_pencils = 10;
    number_of_notebooks = 3;

    printf("%c%c needs %d pencils, %d notebooks, and 1 lunchbox\n",
        firstInitial, middleInitial,number_of_pencils,
        number_of_notebooks);
    printf("The total cost is £%.2f\n\n", number_of_pencils*pencills
        + number_of_notebooks*notebooks + lunchbox);

    //The information for the third child
    firstInitial = 'M';
    middleInitial = 'T';

    number_of_pencils = 9;
    number_of_notebooks = 2;

    printf("%c%c needs %d pencils, %d notebooks, and 1 lunchbox\n",
        firstInitial, middleInitial,number_of_pencils,
        number_of_notebooks);
    printf("The total cost is £%.2f\n",
        number_of_pencils8pencils + number_of_notebooks*notebooks + lunchbox);

        return0;
}

)
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When you have a compilation error, it is best to include the exact error message — except that if the file name is a mile long absolute path, reduce the name to just the base name of the file (so change `/huge/long/path/with/many/levels/of/directory/src/file.o` to just `file.o`).  Make sure the source you show and the line numbers in it match what the compiler says.  If the file is too long for comfort, create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I think the last character `)` should be right after `main(` so -> `main()` Does that do the trick for you? (BTW: `return0;` -> `return 0;`)

Comment: I looked at the sample material for the book, and (in chapter 2) the sample programs all have `main()` rather than `int main()` (or, as I'd prefer, `int main(void)`). They do include the `return 0;` that's necessary since they aren't using C99 notations which permit the `return 0;` to be omitted (though I don't like code that does that, either). The 3rd Edition is dated 2014; it is a bit worrying that the first programs haven't been written in current C for about 15 years now. I don't like its characterization of `return`, `while`, `int`, `if`, `float` as 'commands' — they're keywords! Beware!

Comment: @Dave:
Please mark one answer as solution. And if you can: delete your "thank you answer" as this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your main function is not good.The compiler says it.

It should look like

```
main()
{
....
}
```

Instead of

```
main(
{
...
}
)
```

Comment: In modern C (anything written since 2000), the `main()` function should have the explicit return type of `int`, regardless of whether the compiler actually insists on it or not.  Every function should have an explicit return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` function starts:

```
main(
{
```

and ends:

```
}
)
```

This is wrong.  It should be:

```
int main(void)
{
    …body of function…
}
```

The `void` is optional.  The return type is not optional in modern C (the C89/C90 standard allowed it to be optional; C99 and later requires it; you should program as if it is required even if your compiler doesn't insist on it).  The correct return type is `int` (but see [What should `main` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for the full details).

Also, as [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769988/error-expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-token/27770021#comment43950913_27770021), have `return0;` at the end of `main()`; that should be `return 0;`.

I've not compiled the code to see what other errors there are, but the mishandling of parentheses and braces was the cause of the initial error.

Comment: Also he did `return0;` he have to add a space there